# How to include code39 fonts ttf file and use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using code39 to display bar codes.but due to some reason i can't use the code39 font below is my code. I have included the ttf file in fonts folder.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@Styles.Render("~/fonts")
```

```
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            @{
                string size = "0px";
                int co = Model.BarCodeItems.FirstOrDefault().Columns;
                if (co <= 2)
                {
                    size = "90px";
                }
                if (co > 2 || co < 5)
                {
                    size = "70px";
                }
                if (co >= 5)
                {
                    size = "40px";
                }
                int count = 0;
            }
            @foreach (var items in Model.BarCodeItems)
            {


                <td style="text-align:center">
                    <p style="font-family:Code39r;font-size:@size"> @items.BarCode</p>
                    <p> @items.BarCode</p>

                    @*<ol class="" style="width:5px">@items.BarCode.Replace("*", "")</ol>*@

                </td>
                count++;
                if (count == @items.Columns)
                {
                <tr></tr>
                    count = 0;
                }




            }
            </tr>
        </table>
```

below is my bundle config I have add it in Bundle Config and also render it in my page.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/fonts").Include(
            "~/fonts/Code39r.ttf"));


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has to include a font reference not through `StyleBundle` (it's not a plain text file `text/css` but a binary file, bundles a minifier won't *understand* it and it'll be included wrongly with `<style src="...">` tag) but inside your CSS with `@font-face`. For example, to embed it in your HTML code:

```
<style>
    @@font-face {
        font-family: Code39r; src: url('@Url.Content("~/fonts/Code39r.ttf")'); 
    } 
</style>
```

Note that `@font-face` has to be escaped into `@@font-face` (because Razor will recognize `@`). If you use it in your CSS you can't (unless you'll do some trickery) resolve path using `Url.Content()` then path you specify must be relative to your CSS file, for example:

```
@font-face { font-family: Code39r; src: url('../fonts/Code39r.ttf'); }
```